# Thanks for visiting - can you please also vote on the main site?

Tags: discussion, site-activity, site-analysis

With four-thousands-rep delay I was granted access to "Site Analytics" (I am joking -most probably they weren't previously available for a nascent site like ours).
And they provide some raw data. What did I find?

Starting from **mid-May to August-end 2015**, Visits hold strong and getting stronger (weekly data, to clear the eye):

[image]

**But votes exhibit a clear and consistent downward linear trend:**

[image]

A simple "constant-and deterministic-trend" OLS regression gives (rounded)

$$ \hat V = 360 - 11t$$

Each week, on average we register  $11$ votes less than the previous week. If the trend continues, **in 16 weeks we will record "zero votes per week".**, just-in-time to celebrate the end-of-year holiday season...

There is a song lyric by Was(Not Was) which comments on the JFK assassination  saying

**"Eleven miles an hour / such a deadly speed..."**

You know how it is: the point and the suggestion is *not* to "vote whatever appears in the main". The issue is to adopt an attitude that **votes on the main site are *not* "precious gems of appreciation", but a tool to excite the site activity**. At least, this is how I understand voting on SE sites.

**SHOCKING NEWS**

Although the voting endeavor rests on the behavior of the many, I looked at the "votes cast" of the top-five users(in terms of main-site reputation). And it appears that the user with the highest reputation *(ehem, that's me...)* has also the lowest number of votes cast. I respectfully had to tell him (with a grim face) that this is not a good example-setting practice, and that he should seriously consider mending it. I understand the SE policy is "Be nice", but I always interpret this as "be nice to each other", not necessarily "be nice to one's own self".

Comment: I upvoted this.

Comment: @Foobar Mainward!

Comment: I think people are missunderstanding the request: You're not required to vote on this post, ur supposed to vote on the actual site x(

Comment: @FooBar Did some editing to try to clarify this.