# Site data Nov 2016 Oct 2017

Tags: discussion, site-analysis

[**Back in May-Aug 2015**](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1431/61), we had weekly visits around $4,000$ **per week**, and declining votes that had reached below $200$ per week.

At [**September 2016**](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1626/61) visits for the pat-12-months were at around $10,000$ weekly and jumping at the end of the sample period, while votes, after having rebounced initially, followed also a downward trend down to near $100$ weekly.

**Let's look at the data for the last 12-months, Nov-2016 to Oct 2017** (all data are weekly).

**A) The *very* good news : Visits. Are we becoming the go-to place?**

[image]

Already in Oct 2016 we were at ~$17.000$. After expected slumps around New Year's Holidays and Summer (that still stayed well above the 2015 figure, for example for summer the traffic in 2017 was double the traffic in 2015), we are now flying at $25.000$ feet -excuse me, **visits per week.**

**B) The good news: We take care of our visitors - Questions and Answers**

[image]

The concurrent Pearson's correlation coefficient between Questions and Answers is $0.70$ , which is a good, solid strong correlation. The lagged-once and lagged-twice metrics are less than half this value. This indicates that we respond within a week and a rise in questions causes a rise in answers (I would argue causation here without doubts).

Average questions per week were $47$ for the period, ~$7$ per week, still away from the "$10$ per week" SE-criterion for graduation. But one can also detect a slow upwards trend.

**C) The bad news: Votes love the "$200$ per week" figure and tend to return there...**
[image]

It is obvious from the figure that the voting activity must be metaphysically chained to the number $200$...

We have discussed the issue in the past. To me, **it is a strong indication of vulnerability**. It says that there are too few contributors/active participants on the site, even for this easy, one-click activity.

The floor is yours.

Comment: The Questions and Answers chart seems to imply an average of about one answer per question.  Is that correct, and if so isn't it less than healthy?

Comment: @AdamBailey SE measures the answer ratio as "answers per questions that have been answered" (not counting unanswered questions). I think this is indeed more suitable, because the reasons for unanswered questions may be many more (e.g. very specialized questions etc). This "answer ratio"  is $1.6$ as given here, https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61732/economics,  I.e. in every two questions that are answered, one gets one answer and the other gets two.There you will read that "$2.5$ is good". I believe this is too much, it would be enough for me to go to a value of $2$.

Comment: (+1) Let me just upvote this question to get over the daily 200 level :). Forgive the newbie remark, but are Econ Meta questions included in these stats?

Comment: @MaartenPunt No, the stats are only for the main site.

Comment: This is superb work, as usual, Alecos. I agree that two answers per "reasonable" question would be a good target to work towards. My intuition is that the main obstacle to further progress is currently turning new users into regular users. I have spotted one or two new arrivals in the last months who clearly know more than a thing or two about economics and have stuck around. They are the type who will regularly vote and write answers, so we should do what we can to make the site attractive for them.

Comment: @Ubiquitous Yes... and the market is tight...

Comment: =D at several comment here. I agree with you.